# Error in passing managedobjectcontext from Tab bar controller to TableviewController using navigationController?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsmanagedobject

I have a `tab bar controller` that is connected to a `navigationController`.

The `navigationController` is connected to 3 `TableviewControllers` and the problem I am having is that the `managedobject` is not passed correctly ; I have it as `Nil` , the error message is :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a
>   legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name
>   'MyEntityName'

Before I added `navigationController` I had the `tab bar controller` connected directly to my three `TableviewControllers` and the `managedObject` gets passed correctly, any idea what I am doing wrong ?

This is my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` code in `AppDelegate` :

```
 UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    for (id viewController in [tabBarController viewControllers]) {
        if ([viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setManagedObjectContext:)]) {
            [viewController setManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        }
    }
```

PS: If you need additional peaces of code to understand my issue I'll be glad to post it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing my code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` ; my new code is :

```
 UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    NSArray *allTabs = tabBarController.viewControllers;

    // Navigation Controller in the tab of BreakFasts
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [allTabs objectAtIndex:0];
    MyTableViewController *controller1 = (MyTableViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
    controller1.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```